# After script page will load first at wrong section and not at header of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbounce

I had use Unbounce to create a landing page. In my landing page I installed the following script in order to create a form with multiple steps:

https://gist.github.com/noahub/b8c6d63abb50048d42ee721c900450df

The problem I have with script is that my landing pages first loads at the section where the form is. It does not loads at the top of header. You can see it here http://ar-vida.primerolafamilia.com.ar/seguro_vida1/

What can I do to have landing loads always first at the top?.

Thanks.

Max

Comment: Looks like a `.focus()` issue to me.